# Pygattlib unauthorized access to the memory [Ubuntu 16.4]

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem with communication throw the BLE (via pygattlib) on my ubuntu laptop.
Everithing is ok until I want to write ("write_by_handle") or read ("read_by_handle_async") from BLE -> after that console gives me:

> Unauthorized access to the memory (SIGSEGV) (core dumped [memory image saved])

I have not seen this error before and nothing found on google.

I have running this python3 script as a sudo user.
I have been using example script from pygattlib. (https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib)

Thanks Mike

Comment: I see you already filed an issue on the project, but you should update it with more details.  A code snippet that recreates the bug would be helpful to the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a bug on bluez.

I just update bluez manualy to the newest version:

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.44.tar.xz
tar xvf bluez-5.44.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.44
./configure --prefix=/usr           \
            --mandir=/usr/share/man \
            --sysconfdir=/etc       \
            --localstatedir=/var    \
            --enable-library        \
            --disable-systemd       \
            --disable-android       
make
sudo make install
```